# How can I see a description of the error that has occurred in Node.js/Express when the back-end is used just as an API?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a Vue.js front-end and a Node.js/Express back-end and right now I'm trying to make a POST request to a certain route. The POST request goes through flawlessly but as soon as I add some code in the function, I get a `POST /createServer 500` error in the console and I can't figure out what this error actually is. This is why I'm wondering where can I get a detailed description of what's happening so I can fix the error?

This works:

```
router.post('/createServer', function(req, res, next) {
    let server = req.body

    console.log('Working fine')

    })
});
```

But as soon as I tried to do something in the function, I started getting the vague error in the console.log().

```
router.post('/createServer', function(req, res, next) {
    let server = req.body

    io.of(server.endpoint).on('connection',(socket) => {
        socket.on('messageToServer', (message) => {
            let roomName = Object.keys(socket.rooms)[1]
            let room = server.room.find((room) => {
                return room.name == roomName
            })

            room.history.push(message)

            io.of(server.endpoint).to(roomName).emit('messageToClient', message)
        })

        socket.on('joinRoom', (roomToJoin) => {
            let roomToLeave = Object.keys(socket.rooms)[1]
            let room = server.room.find((room) => {
                return room.name == roomToJoin
            })

            socket.leave(roomToLeave)
            socket.join(roomToJoin)

            socket.emit('chatHistory', room.history)
        })

    })
});
```

Comment: Where are you using console.log to see the error? Can you post the full error message?

Comment: Well the full error is - POST /createServer 500 165.386 ms - 1153. I'm not console.logging it myself so I assume it's Express' doing.

Comment: In your question you literally say this: "But as soon as I tried to do something in the function, I started getting the vague error in the console.log()." .......

Comment: What happens if you [try something like this](https://gist.github.com/oze4/34e3f4908f3fbef44bb58b1f9be46890)?

Comment: Did you've tried use "error" event like you do at "on connection"? But, if your error are not when you connect in io, you need  listen the "error" event at socket too. Test those things and update your code, please.